# Considerations for responsiveness of web application using SQLite and Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, web-applications

I'm planning to create a web based application for restaurant billing for my client. The technology is Spring, hibernate. Since my client is not inclined to any browsers, I will ask him to go with Firefox. Planning to deploy my App in Tomcat instance in his local machine.
This is my first real time deployment. I have planned to use SQLite in Firefox to give at least 70% of responsive time of desktop application. How do I make my application more stable since he will be using it round the clock? Will the responsiveness of my application deteriorate in days? I don't have any clear forecast on this.

Comment: You should probably be a little more specific in your question... (Also, I hope your client is not paying you too much for that kind of service!)

Comment: My question is that since  it is  web based application will have the same response time as that of desktop based application. Should I need to look into some other features to make it more stable.Did i miss out any important feature for application. Billing  has simple Architectural functionality and business . For your info he is gives a fairly reasonable price ..!!! :)

Comment: stability and responsiveness are two different things. What are you asking exactly? What is the relation between SQLite in Firefox and Hibernate? How could we tell if the responsiveness could deteriorate? You haven't done anything yet, and the architecture of your app looks quite mysterious.